# How do I get my projects to use a global .eslintrc file by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atom-editor, eslint

I use atom text editor. 
Here are the steps I took to get my linter working with React and ES6:

- install atom-react package
- when I start a new project, I run `npm install --save eslint`
- create an .eslintrc file in my project folder (this can be done either manually or running command `eslint --init`, which helps create the file with a series of questions that I answer on the command line)

I don't want to have to create the .eslintrc everytime I start coding a new project. I want to use the global .eslintrc file, which I found when I:

- Go to Atom > Preferences
- Click on Open Config Folder
- Click on .atom > packages > linter > .eslintrc

How can I make it so that when I fire up a new file and start coding I already get the options defined in this global file?

In particular, this is the setup I am using in individual projects:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-react"
  ]
}
```

And I want this to be the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to settings --> packages --> linter-eslint settings. On that menu, look for the `.eslintrc Path` option. For your particular preference, you would put `~/.atom/packages/linter/.eslintrc` in that field. Your `.eslintrc` is now being used globally across all of your projects.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the configuration cascading to your advantage :
http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy

```
workspace
     |
     |_ .eslintrc (global, root = true)
     |
     |_ project-1
           |       
           |_ .eslintrc (project specific, if you need to overwrite some rules)
```

From the eslint documentation:

[image]